# Setting and removing jQuery cookie based on click() of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to set and remove a cookie with a click like so ..

**My HTML**

```
<button id="listing_123" class="add-listing">Add to Itinerary</button>
<button id="listing_456" class="add-listing">Add to Itinerary</button>
<button id="listing_789" class="add-listing">Add to Itinerary</button>
```

**My jQuery:** This lets me set the cookie just fine (but i have to refresh the page to view the cookie).

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.add-itinerary').click(function() {

        var lid = $(this).attr('id');

        $.cookie('add_listing_'+ lid, 1, { expires: 30 });

        $(this).toggleClass('added');
        $(this).html($(this).text() == 'Remove' ? 'Add to Itinerary' : 'Remove');

    })

})
```

**Problem 1:** When the page refreshes I lose my "added" class and the .html() goes back to "Add" ... How can I keep my class on the items that were clicked based on the cookie that was set.

**Problem 2:** When I click the button the 2nd time i need the "added" class removed and the cookie removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.add-itinerary').click(function () {
        var lid = this.id,
            cookie = $.cookie('add_listing_' + lid);
        if (cookie == 1) {
            $.removeCookie('add_listing_' + lid)
        } else {
            $.cookie('add_listing_' + lid, 1, {
                expires: 30
            });
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('added');
        $(this).html($(this).text() == 'Remove' ? 'Add to Itinerary' : 'Remove');
    }).each(function () {
        if ($.cookie('add_listing_' + this.id) == 1) {
            $(this).addClass('added').text('Remove')
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C2m2r/)

Comment: EDIT: how would I go about storing the "lid" as a comma seperated value for the "add_listing" cookie?

Currently it is replacing the cookie value rather than adding to it?